# Three.js - Why shadow only show in a small area

Tags: javascript, three.js, model

I imported a model and found that shadow only show in a small area(green area in the picture). What can I do to let all objects show their shadow.

[image]

Here is my code.

```js
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.01; // same as the camera
light.shadow.camera.far = 1000; // same as the camera
light.shadow.camera.fov = 50; // same as the camera
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
scene.add( light );
```

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

I add `gui` to change `light.shadow.camera.top` / `light.shadow.camera.bottom` / `light.shadow.camera.left` / `light.shadow.camera.right`, but nothing happens.

```js
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add( light.shadow.camera, 'top' ).min( 1 ).max( 100000 ).onChange( function ( value ) {
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -value;
    light.shadow.camera.left = value;
    light.shadow.camera.right = -value;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, it would be great if you could show me a live example of your code as I have fixed this before for a project in [boxelizer.com](https://boxelizer.com/renderer.php?mid=6bde732006484c20aa72b85624bc629d)

The issue can be fixed by changing the **light.shadow.camera.left, right, bottom and top properties** as suggested before, however we might not be able to see what the effective area of our shadow might be and hence we might be really close to fixing it but not at all. My suggestion is using a helper momentarily just to see the effective shadow area of your light with:

```
var shadowHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
scene.add( shadowHelper );
```

You are also welcome to see all the code I used in the link I referenced to.

Comment: Hi, I have added my complete code in my question. I use `new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera )` and find that the scale is too small. Could you tell me how to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: @Tiffany I think I spotted the issue here, try not defining the values of light.shadow.camera.left, right, bottom and top inside of the GUI widget, please define them before even calling the light into the scene with scene.add( light ), I bet that should fix your thing. (And if it does I will edit my answer)

Comment: It works! but looks wired. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YkkCXEE.png).

Comment: Oh, you are right it looks weird, how many directional lights (casting shadow) do you have on stage?

Comment: Just one directional light :( I also change the position of the directional light. All shadows are rendered but it cause another proplem. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/tvwa3dd.png).

Comment: Maybe I should create a question to ask this on stackoverflow. `CameraHelper` really helps me a lot. thanks!

Comment: Give you the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034734/three-js-what-causes-shadow-acne-and-how-to-fix-it) of my new question although you deleted the comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

That's happening because directional lights use an `OrthographicCamera` to draw a shadowmap to cast shadows. If there are objects outside the view of this camera, it won't be able to calculate their shadows, and will have the effect you're seeing outside the green box. If you want to extend the area that this camera covers, you can modify the `.left .right .top .bottom` properties of this shadow camera to cover your entire scene. I'm using a box of 100 units in the example below;

```
var side = 100;
light.shadow.camera.top = side;
light.shadow.camera.bottom = -side;
light.shadow.camera.left = side;
light.shadow.camera.right = -side;
```

... but you can change the dimensions to whatever you need. Keep in mind that `.fov` does nothing in your example code because ortho cameras don't use the field-of-view property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I try to change `light.shadow.camera.top` / `light.shadow.camera.bottom` / `light.shadow.camera.left` / `light.shadow.camera.right`, but nothing happens :(
I have edited my question.

Comment: Try changing the values directly first before adding it to the GUI. Otherwise you're adding too many changes simultaneously and you won't know which part is breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use to set the shadowMap dimensions and coverage area:

```
//sz is the size in world units that the shadow should cover. (area)
// mapSize is the width,height of the texture to be used for shadowmap (resolution)
    var setShadowSize=(light1, sz, mapSz)=>{
        light1.shadow.camera.left = sz;
        light1.shadow.camera.bottom = sz;
        light1.shadow.camera.right = -sz;
        light1.shadow.camera.top = -sz;
        if(mapSz){
            light1.shadow.mapSize.set(mapSz,mapSz)
        }
    }
    setShadowSize(myLight,15.0,1024);
```