# Three.js what causes shadow acne and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, three.js, model

In order to let all shadows be rendered, I set `shadow.camera.top` / `bottom` / `left` / `right` to the directional light (casting shadow), but it causes shadow acne. 
I try to use `shadow.bias` but still not right. What causes shadow acne and how to fix it?

[image]

Here is my code.

```js
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 38, 82, 1 );
light.castShadow = true;
// light.shadow.bias = -0.001;
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;  // same as the camera
light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;  // same as the camera
light.shadow.camera.top = 120;
light.shadow.camera.bottom = -120;
light.shadow.camera.left = 120;
light.shadow.camera.right = -120;
scene.add( light );
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? It's strange when tweaking `light.shadow.bias` does no help. BTW: The shadow camera does not have to use the same `near` and `far` values like the actual camera for rendering the scene. I suggest you use `THREE.CameraHelper` to visualize the shadow camera and make the frustum as tight as possible. You can create the helper like so `scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );`.

Comment: Here is my [complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/tiffk935/k15yombc/). :)

Comment: It seems the fiddle does not work since the JSON file is not loaded correctly from your backend (I can see in the network tab just the status "Pending"). Can you please share the JSON file here? I can then make a local test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `shadow.bias` to `- 0.0005` seems to remove the shadow artifacts. However, the quality of the shadows are still not good since the edges of the shadows look very blocky.

Consider setting the property `renderer.shadowMap.type` to `THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap` which will noticeable improve the shadow quality. It might also be a good idea to reduce the size of the shadow camera's frustum and only cast shadow in a certain "focus" area. Another option is to bake a high quality lighting into a light map and then apply it to the `lightMap` property of the city's material. You can also just increase the resolution of the shadow map to `4096 x 4096` but this will have a performance impact, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: I change `light1.shadow.camera.left = side;` to `light1.shadow.camera.left = -side;` and `light1.shadow.camera.right = -side;` to `light1.shadow.camera.right = side;`. It looks much better.

Comment: I think baking by 3DsMax or blender is the best solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting shadow.bias= -0.01 helps me, but I also lower intensity and shadow looks good.