# Three.js light looks like something moire

Tags: three.js

[The scene picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n0RH.png)

I have put a PointLight to the scene and shadows look like some kind of strips or smth like "moiré pattern"

The code is:

```
window.light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xDDDDDD, 1, 100 );
        light2.intensity = 5;
        light2.decay = 1;  
        light2.position.set(-33, 12, 0);
        light2.castShadow = true;
        light2.receiveShadow = true; 
        scene.add( light2 );    
      }
```

I found that it's occurs when I have gltf objects with "receiveShadow = true" on the scene. This effect apears on the lightened parts.

Update: Alse I found that surface of of my gltf objects (I make them in Blender) is not flat when it is lightened. For example, surface of a cube:

[Cube picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIxaU.png)

[Zoomed cube picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8K1W.png)

But this is only when cube has material.

Comment: This looks like shadow acne (i.e. what occurs when light is close to parallel to the surface, "close" depending on scale and bias parameters). This question and answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034734/three-js-what-causes-shadow-acne-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Thanks:-) I tried that but I have no result. This problem occurs only when I use scene that I save from Blender. But model from https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Soldier.glb renders ok: https://jsfiddle.net/a3zsdLvt/2/

Comment: And this is my scene glb: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/scpTSWwDrSU-Nw